# Get current_user in devise token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I have an app, where devise token authentication is used from here https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication. There, I use token authentication only for specific actions f.e. edit, update, destroy, but not for index or show. That's why when I call in edit `current_user`, I get those params, that I need, but when it's action like index, where there's no token authentication, but the user is still signed in, I get `nil`.
I thought off one solution is to use sessions, but I think it's not that good of solution.
 So maybe you can propose some other kind of black magic solution to it. Thx for answering.

Comment: try setting `config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = false` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Comment: doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: You could set `@user = User.where(authentication_token: request.env["HTTP_X_HTTP_CLIENT_TOKEN"]).last` in your base controller and use it in the corresponding controllers where you want to access the user

Comment: This is a very bad idea.